# Apache POI XSSFWorkbook creates drop down list for a large excel file in Java

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi

I have a large excel file, about 250k rows. I want to create a drop down list for one column. The question is XSSFworkbook cannot handle this size of file (jvm heap out of memory). And streaming model (SXXFwork) does not have formula validation feature. This is the doc: [POI-HSSF and POI-XSSF](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html)

Does anyone have a solution? Thank you !

Comment: Increase your heap size, and stick with XSSF?

Comment: @Gagravarr  Someone did a test that it costs 1Gb memory to process about 10k rows (this is not verified). Increase JVM heap size may help a little bit, but cannot solve this problem. Plus, my tech lead does not want to change heap size.   Thanks for your answer anyway.

Comment: You can use the [SSPerformanceTest tool as detailed in the FAQ](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10109) to check exactly how much memory POI needs for a given number of rows and columns